# Integrate Facebook With PhoneGap @ Android

Tags: cordova

How do I integrate Facebook API into PhoneGap for Android? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at my recent blog post, I describe a step by step guide to integrate facebook inside of PhoneGap:

http://blog.lagentz.com/?p=23

Answer (score 1):

Try the new Facebook Plugin!

http://blogs.nitobi.com/andre/index.php/2011/08/30/get-the-phonegap-facebook-connect-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

I setup a Xcode project with the PhoneGap/Cordova 1.70 framework and Facebook plugin installed. The Hackbook web views have also been implemented, you can get it from https://github.com/rezbuilt/facebook-connect-phonegap-framework

Answer (score 1):

Use FaceGap, software that I have developed: https://github.com/studiosoton/faceGap